# Apple script is giving syntax error

Tags: applescript, osx-elcapitan

I want to auto accept a screen share invitation from a certain account in my messages app.

I went to the Auto Accept.applescript and added the following

```
on received local screen sharing invitation from theBuddy for theChat
    accept theChat
end received local screen sharing invitation
```

but when I try to save it, I get "Syntax error Expected “given”, “into”, “with”, “without” or other parameter name but found “local”."

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to wrap the code in a

```
using terms from application "Messages"


end using terms from
```

block. But what version of `Messages.app` has an `on received local screen sharing invitation from theBuddy for theChat` event ??

**Edit**:

Screen sharing invitations are video invitations, the event `local screen sharing invitation` does not exist.

```
using terms from application "Messages"
   on received video invitation theText from theBuddy for theChat
       set buddySN to (get handle of theBuddy)
       set allowedBuddy to "myAccount"
       if (buddySN is allowedBuddy) then
           accept theChat
       end if
   end received video invitation
end using terms from
```

Comment: what can I do to auto accept screen sharing invitations from a certain user ? I am using el capitan

Comment: do i change "myAccount" to the apple ID that I want to accept?

Comment: Yes, the `handle` represents the email address or telephone number or AIM name.

Comment: Is it possible to talk to you via some chat app? It isnt working for me, and I am not understanding why...

Comment: No, I'm afraid, first of all you have to put the script into `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.iChat/` and then select it in the preferences of Messages.app but event scripting in Messages.app seems to be not very reliable anyway.